# github action always allow to create new workflow while whereas we have existing yaml fille, how to select?

Tags: github, github-actions

trying git hub action first time, but found this is difficult how to select existing workflow yaml file? in UI every time I click to browse workflow, it give range of options but how to select exiting one? is this limited due to beta version or wghat I am missing here

go to Settings > Github Page > Build And Deployement > Source
[image: Github pages choose Github Action]

and click on browe all workflow then open this page

[image: choose a wrokflow page]

now when click on **Node.js** tile configure page, it opens UI to create new file,
[image: creat new workflow page opens]

I already have created 2 files but where is the option to select existing one?

Comment: The file is added to the repository in the `.github/workflows` folder, all of the files are there, browse to them in the `code` tab.

Comment: Yes I am not asking for how to see the existing file code but how to choose existing file as my workflow। Right now there are 3 workflows are there

Comment: They are *all* your workflow. If you want to have only 1, just delete the other 2.

Comment: In the Actions tab on the left you can choose which workflow to run in case you want to keep all 3.